# Show that $f(x)=x^3-5x$ is an injective map from $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question is:

> If $f(x)=x^3-5x$, show that for rational $x$ and $y$, $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$.

If $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$, then: $$x(x^2-5)=y(y^2-5).$$ Now, $x^2-5=y^2-5 \iff y=\pm\, x$. Putting this above gives only the possibility $x=y$, but I don't think this is the right way to go about it. Help/hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have gone on as $$x(x^2-5)=y(y^2-5)$$ or, $$x^3-y^3-5x+5y=0$$ or, $$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2-5)=0$$

Now $x^2+xy+y^2-5=0$ has non-rational roots only.

so $x=y \Rightarrow f$ is injective.

**EDIT:**(by peter a g)

You have to show that $x^2+xy+y^2=5$ has no rational solution, and that's a bit of an exercise. First rule out that $5$ appears in the numerators or denominators of $x$ and $y$ - or, if you know the language of $p$-adic fields, show $x$ and $y$ are $5$-adic units. Then, having ruled that out, the problem reduces to showing that
$$x^2+xy+y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod5$$
has no non-trivial solutions integer solutions, or that
$$t^2+t+1 \equiv 0 \pmod5$$
has no integral solutions.

Comment: To add to Aniket's answer... you have to show that $x^2+xy+y^2=5$ has no rational solution, and that's a bit of an exercise. First rule out that $5$ appears in the numerators or denominators of $x$ and $y$ - or, if you know the language of $p$-adic fields, show $x$ and $y$ are $5$-adic units. Then, having ruled that out, the problem reduces to showing that $$ x^2+ xy +y^2\equiv 0\pmod 5$$ has no non-trivial solutions integer solutions, or that $$ t^2+t +1 \equiv 0\pmod 5$$ has no integral solutions.

Comment: @peterag Thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bijection. It is only injective. For example there is no rational number $x$, s.t. $x^3-5x=1$.

Comment: As follows immediately from the rational roots theorem.